# Inappbrowser in angular2/ionic2 with ionic view testing

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, ionic2, inappbrowser

I am trying to integrate ionic2 Inappbrowser for getting oauth2 token. Since Inappbrowser plugin is not supported by Ionic View (We use ionic view for testing), using Inappbrowser doesn't seem to be an option. Tried using window.open and adding en event listener, that didn't work though. Any idea on how to make getting oauth2 token which works in ionic view, would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance